# Perl regex match string by not consuming characters

Tags: regex, perl

How do I extract the string in between but not consuming the characters,

The string:

```
abc123
def456
ghi789
```

I was using the regex below and it returns the string in between 123 and 789:

```
/123(.*?)789/s
```

What I want to extract is:

```
123
def456
ghi789
```

Comment: Umm... `/(123.*?789)/s` ?

Comment: Maybe `(123)(\D+?\d+)(.*?789)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capturing parens should be placed around what you want to capture, so replace

```
/123(.*?)789/s
```

with

```
/(123.*?789)/s
```

Now, `123` and `789` will be included in the captured text as requested.